# Are there ALIPAY APIs for PHP integration?

Tags: php

I am looking to integrate http://alipay.com, a chinese payment platform with my php-project. are there any free  or opensource api's that one can leverage  (with documentation preferably in english language) ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you got any solution for this?

Comment: please share if you have found any solution for this integration.

Answer (score 1):

Website integration can be written using libcurl (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

libcurl supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading (this can also be done with PHP's ftp extension), HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication and several other protocols.

Comment: Is there documentation on using HTTP to access Alipay?

Comment: you got any solution for this?